# Graficos estadisticos en barras y ordenado por fechas

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gráficas

Estoy haciendo una app de ingresos gastos y ahorros quiero hacer que ingresos gastos y ahorros representados en forma de barras que serian 3 y poderlas ordenarlas por semana mes y año y compararlos cuanto ingreso cuanto gasto y cuanto ahorro  cada uno con sus colores respectivos azul ingreso rojo gasto y morado ahorro ya tengo la base de datos estuve trabajando y lo almaceno donde pido al usuario fecha con el dialogpicker estuve buscando librias como hellochart y barchart pero son mas estadisticos .... Gracias

Comment: Hace algún tiempo tuve una pregunta similar, terminé optando por usar [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), cuenta con muy buena documentación y ejemplos.

Comment: se puede con GraphView. Muestra tu código java donde quieres mostrar el gráfico